# Probability that a Linear Combination of Dirichlet Random Variables is a Distribution

Tags: random-variable, dirichlet-distribution, hoeffdings-inequality

I've been putting a lot of thought on this problem, but it seems I ran out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated!  Suppose we generate two probability vectors $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1, \boldsymbol{\theta}_2 \sim \operatorname{IID Dirichlet}(\boldsymbol{\alpha}) \in \mathbb{R}^L$  where $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_L)$ with $\alpha_1 = \ldots = \alpha_L = 1$.

Now, suppose we take a scalar value $a \geq 1$ and we define the vector $\mathbf{X}$ as:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X} = a \boldsymbol{\theta}_1 + (1-a) \boldsymbol{\theta}_2.
\end{equation}

It is clear that $\sum X_i = 1$, so the norming requirement of probability is met.  In order for $\mathbf{X}$ to be a probability vector we also need $\mathbf{X} \geqslant \mathbf{0}$.  How can I compute the probability that this is true?

---

**What I have tried:** I've tried looking at [Chen (2013)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Concentration-Inequalities-for-Bounded-Random-Chen/164e3955eeacf19774ea1e412bb290d0e8b47502) to solve this problem but the $z$ in there seems too restrictive.  (I may also not be using their results correctly.)  I have also tried using another trick using [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality), but none of my methods have worked.  I'm also new on the ideas of concentration bounds, so that may have been a problem too.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do $a$ and $b$ represent scalars or are they vectors that are intended to be multiplied componentwise (as suggested by your notation "$X\ge 0$")? Given that the components of the $\theta_i$ sum to unity, the sum of the components of $X$ must be $a+b,$ so can we infer $a+b=1$?  (Your assumption "$a\ge 0$ and $b\le 0$" suggests you might have something else in mind.)

Comment: Hi! Oh, yeah, I forgot to mention that $X \geq 0$ is component wise! Thanks for the catch! Sure, you are right, $a + b = 1$, but I don't think this will be very useful here. I added the assumption, just to make sure $P(X \geq 0) \neq 1$. It also reflects exactly the problem I have at hand.

Comment: Also, yeah, $a$ and $b$ are scalars.

Comment: Since $a+b=1$ this means that $b = 1-a$ and so you can easily simplify your presentation of the problem to use only the single scalar $a$.  I have taken the liberty of making a major edit to your question to reduce it to a single scalar and make other edits for clarity.  Please feel free to revert if this does not correctly encapsulate your question.

Comment: Hello @Ben! Thanks a lot for your help, even at rewriting parts of my question (you see, I am new around here and in statistics as a whole). I'll keep the changes you made. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To facilitate analysis, we will define the scalar value $\phi \equiv (a-1)/a$, which will serve as an alternative parameterisation of the problem.  Using this value you can rewrite the probability of interest as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X} \geqslant \mathbf{0})
&= \mathbb{P}(a \boldsymbol{\theta}_1 + (1-a) \boldsymbol{\theta}_2 \geqslant \mathbf{0}) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(a \boldsymbol{\theta}_1 \geqslant (a-1) \boldsymbol{\theta}_2) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \Big( \boldsymbol{\theta}_1 \geqslant \frac{a-1}{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{\theta}_2 \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}( \boldsymbol{\theta}_1 \geqslant \phi\cdot  \boldsymbol{\theta}_2), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Since $0 \leqslant \phi < 1$, your question boils down to finding the probability that one Dirichlet random variable is at least as large (componentwise) as some positive proportion (less than one) of another identically distributed Dirichlet random variable.

So far as I am aware, there is no closed form expression for this probability.  It can be written as an integral over the joint density function of the random variables:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X} \geqslant \mathbf{0})
&= \mathbb{P}( \boldsymbol{\theta}_1 \geqslant \phi \cdot \boldsymbol{\theta}_2), \\[6pt]
&= \iint \limits_{\boldsymbol{\theta}_1 \geqslant \phi \cdot \boldsymbol{\theta}_2} \ \text{Dirichlet}(\boldsymbol{\theta}_1|\boldsymbol{\alpha}) \text{Dirichlet}(\boldsymbol{\theta}_2|\boldsymbol{\alpha}) \ d\boldsymbol{\theta}_1 d \boldsymbol{\theta}_2. \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{\text{B}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})^2} \iint \limits_{\boldsymbol{\theta}_1 \geqslant \phi\cdot  \boldsymbol{\theta}_2} \prod_{i=1}^L (\theta_{1,i} \theta_{2,i})^{\alpha_i-1} \ d\boldsymbol{\theta}_1 d \boldsymbol{\theta}_2. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In practice you would need to compute this integral using numerical methods, or approximate it using Monte Carlo methods or importance sampling.  So long as $L$ is not too large, it should be possible to compute this probability to a reasonable level of accuracy using Monte Carlo sampling.

Comment: I see. I was afraid I had to end up recurring to numerics or sampling, since a simple bound would suffice to me. It almost "smells" like such a bound exists and it is very straight forward, what do do you think? In any way, the solution you pointed to is very helpful and I might use in my research problem! Thanks a lot for your help!